# How to test a mamp like set-up on CircleCI

Tags: testing, behat, circleci

I have a Codeigniter install and developed locally with MAMP Pro. I have included behat tests which have working ok locally. I am trying to get a CircleCI config that will work like my local set-up works.

My behat.yml file is as follows:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: "http://www.usetiltdev.com/"
            sessions:
                default:
                    goutte: ~
```

And my circleci config file:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.2-apache-browsers

    working_directory: ~/app

    steps:
      - checkout

      #install php extensions needed
      - run: sudo apt install -y libpng-dev
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install gd

      #config apache
      - run: sudo chmod 777 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - run: ls -la
      - run: ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - run: sudo cp design/environment/circleci/site_test.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/usetiltdev.conf
      - run: sudo a2ensite usetiltdev
      - run: sudo service apache2 restart
      - run: echo 127.0.0.1 usetiltdev.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
      - run: echo 127.0.0.1 www.usetiltdev.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
      - run: cat /etc/hosts

      #install composer dependecies
      - run: composer install

      # run tests!
      - run: vendor/bin/behat
```

Lastly here is an example of the test that works locally but not on CircleCI:

```
When I am on "/contact/"
And I fill in "name" with "Joe Bloggs"
    // I get the following error
    Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "name" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
```

I have cross-posted this [to the CircleCI forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/testing-locally-with-mamp-works-but-cannot-get-expected-results-on-circleci/31727).

Comment: Is your test framework firing up a real browser? If so, can you use the browser snapshot feature to see why there is a problem - maybe it is having trouble rendering the page. I would recommend the post-build SSH feature to try a few things, as it is quicker than several commit-push-try cycles.

Comment: (Ah, I see a mention of Goutte, which is a headless non-JS browser written in PHP. If that is your browser then perhaps you can echo the HTML page you hav fetched prior to running a test; perhaps there is an HTTP issue, e.g. the curl extension is not available?)

Comment: @halfer the local tests are taken from a tutorial on https://riptutorial.com/behat. Not really sure what or why specific things were used. The CircleCi config too was trial and error just to get to that point.

Comment: Sure, I reckon it just needs some debugging. Tutorials often don't work first time, and they just need a bit of fiddling to get them to work in a particular environment. I'd recommend checking the PHP logs in the CircleCI environment too.

Comment: This is what I got, not sure if im anywhere near right or wrong.

#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
wget -O - www.usetiltdev.com
--2019-08-06 10:19:10--  http://www.usetiltdev.com/
Resolving www.usetiltdev.com (www.usetiltdev.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to www.usetiltdev.com (www.usetiltdev.com)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-08-06 10:19:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Exited with code 8

Comment: Great, so that's your answer, broadly - the page is not found. You need to find out why that is. I would start at `usetiltdev.conf`, I assume you're using name-based virtual hosting, and Apache is not loading that config. It may also be worth requesting `/` to see if you can fetch the home page - if that is possible then maybe look into your routing.

Comment: Again, an SSH session will be invaluable here.

Comment: Cheers, will look into this more then.